# chrome memory and cpu footprint

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, cpu-load, memory-usage

I've searched the forums for an answer but I couldn't find quite the answer I was looking for [1] , so I thought I it could as well be of interest to more people around here.

I carry out a big part of my job on the browser (or for the browser, if you want to put it that way). I tend to use Chrome, because it's got natively many of the newest features that I need (DevTools stuff, mainly but not only). BTW, I'm usually running the last available Chrome version/build on a desktop Vaio with 4GB RAM and dual core CPU and Ubuntu 12.04 as distro and Gnome as window manager.

So, I was curious about a) why does Chrome spawn so many threads even opening only three of four tabs and b) is there any way to allocate more memory to Chrome to prevent its performance from degrading?

Thanks in advance,

Nacho

PS [1] I found threads about Chrome freezing or running out of memory but not about the reasons for this being so or for avoiding it to happen.

PPS Of course, I could always buy a newer and more capable machine and that is exactly what I'm trying to evaluate: is this a question of outdated hardware or the problem will keep appearing on any (decently but not hugely sized) machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome separates each major part of the browser into separate processes. For example, the browser itself is its own process, each tab is its own process, and each extension is its own process. There's also likely a separate GPU process. (You can see these details by going to about:memory).

Part of the advantage here is the limited access each part has on the other parts. For example, if there was a malicious script in an extension or a tab, then (ideally) it could only affect its own process, and won't bring down the entire browser. If a tab gets frozen for whatever reason, only that tab (and possibly tabs you open from that tab) are brought down, but not the whole browser. (See also about:sandbox.)

You can't pre-allocate memory to Chrome; if Chrome needs more memory, and it is available, then it will take it. Note that the limiting condition may also be on the I/O side, as Chrome has to read your profile, preferences, and at least part of your history on startup and general use. Linux and Unix have a feature that let you store files in RAM, which will result in faster access (reading from memory is faster than reading from the hard drive, and can also reduce wear in the case of many writes), but with a potential loss in data (the contents of the RAM are lost when your computer loses power or shuts down).

There is a script called [profile-sync-daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Profile-sync-daemon) which stores the browser profile and cache in RAM and syncs the profile back to the hard drive every hour. This means that if your computer were to lose power or have a hard shutdown, your profile and history will be at most one hour old. (On normal shutdown, the script syncs back the contents from memory to the hard drive.) See the link above for more installation and [this](https://github.com/graysky2/profile-sync-daemon#ubuntu-users) page for installation in Ubuntu.

Note that Chrome(ium) store the cache separately from your profile, and the script only takes care of the profile (it's outside the scope of the script to manage the cache). You may want to move the cache from the current location into the profile directory, and add a symlink at the old location to the new location.